# Passing message in ViewBag from controller to view in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.Net MVC . I have a view named `Index.cshtml` .I have two actions in `homeController`, `'Index'` and `'saveAttendance'`. First, Index action takes place and the datas from view returned by 'Index' action is sent to 'saveAttendance' action. After all the functions in 'saveAttendance' action is completed I need to return to view to 'Index.cshtml' with a success message in viewbag. I don't have a view assigned to 'saveAttendance'  action. I just need to return to view in 'Index' action.

**My homeController's code:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    try
    {
        ViewBag.nepali_date = dc.ToBS(DateTime.Now);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return View();
}

public void saveAttendance(attendance_entry entryObj)
{
    try
    {
        DateConverter dc = new DateConverter();
        DateTime current_date = entryObj.current_date;
        string nep_date = entryObj.nep_date;
        DateTime current_time = entryObj.current_time;
        string current_day = entryObj.current_day;
        int staff_id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["staff_id"]);
        string in_time = entryObj.in_time;
        string out_time = entryObj.out_time;
       if( DAL.Attendance.Model.exists(staff_id.ToString())!=0)
        {
            ViewBag.message = "Attendance for today is already made.";
            return;
        }
        DAL.Attendance.Model.insert(nep_date, staff_id,current_date, current_time, current_day,in_time,out_time);
        ViewBag.message = "Record saved successfully";
        RedirectToAction("Index");           
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ViewBag.message = "Failed to save attendance record";       
    }

}
```

Comment: Then have the saveAttenance return index view `return View("Index")` or rename `saveAttenance ` to `Index` to handle POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `saveAttenance` to `Index` to handle POST.

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    ViewBag.nepali_date = dc.ToBS(DateTime.Now);
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(attendance_entry entryObj) {
    try {
        var dc = new DateConverter();
        var current_date = entryObj.current_date;
        var nep_date = entryObj.nep_date;
        var current_time = entryObj.current_time;
        var current_day = entryObj.current_day;
        var staff_id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["staff_id"]);
        var in_time = entryObj.in_time;
        var out_time = entryObj.out_time;
        if( DAL.Attendance.Model.exists(staff_id.ToString())!=0) {
            ViewBag.message = "Attendance for today is already made.";                
        } else {
            DAL.Attendance.Model.insert(nep_date, staff_id,current_date, current_time, current_day,in_time,out_time);
            ViewBag.message = "Record saved successfully";
        }
    } catch (Exception) {
        ViewBag.message = "Failed to save attendance record";
    }

    ViewBag.nepali_date = dc.ToBS(DateTime.Now);
    return View();
}
```

And update the form in the view to POST to the the correct action.

Comment: return View(); in last line is showing me in error : cannot convert method group to non-delegate type 'ActionResult '

Comment: sorry sir, but I didn't get you. I changed the action name in view to 'Index' action .

Comment: is the method still void?

Comment: I changed it into ActionResult : 
        public ActionResult Index(attendance_entry entryObj)

Comment: I changed return View(); to return View("Index");  That worked for me. Thank you sir for help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the return type of function **"saveAttendance"** which is void and in the end of "**saveAttendance**" you are doing `RedirectToAction("Index")` which eventually calls the index ActionResult but as **"saveAttendance"** is void you wont be redirected to Index View.

Just make three small tweaks

1. Change `public void saveAttendance(attendance_entry entryObj)` to `public ActionResult Index(attendance_entry entryObj)`
2. In the end of **saveAttendance** function just write
   `Return RedirectToAction("Index");`
   instead of
   `RedirectToAction("Index");`
3. Use `[ChildActionOnly]` so that **saveAttendance** is not accessed by url

Here is the code

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult saveAttendance(attendance_entry entryObj)
        {
            try
            {
                DateConverter dc = new DateConverter();
                DateTime current_date = entryObj.current_date;
                string nep_date = entryObj.nep_date;
                DateTime current_time = entryObj.current_time;
                string current_day = entryObj.current_day;
                int staff_id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["staff_id"]);
                string in_time = entryObj.in_time;
                string out_time = entryObj.out_time;
                if (DAL.Attendance.Model.exists(staff_id.ToString()) != 0)
                {
                    ViewBag.message = "Attendance for today is already made.";
                    return;
                }
                DAL.Attendance.Model.insert(nep_date, staff_id, current_date, current_time, current_day, in_time, out_time);
                ViewBag.message = "Record saved successfully";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ViewBag.message = "Failed to save attendance record";
            }

        }`
```